# Is it possible to traverse a binary tree with a finite-state machine?

Tags: tree-traversal, state-machine

Good day,

Just to be clear: I am not looking for recursive or iterative solutions, Wikipedia has sufficient pseudocode to implement pre-, in- and post-order traversal of any tree.

I am interested in building a finite-state machine to traverse a binary tree.

A Tree consists of Nodes. Nodes have a LeftChild, a RightChild, and a Parent property.

The FSM halts at a Node at any given time, and can have as many states as required, but NO DYNAMIC STACK of any sort (which distinguishes it from a Turing machine). On input "GiveNext" the machine should halt on the next node (say traversing the tree pre-order.)

I've tried for quite a while now, and suspect, that it is not possible, but I am not sure. The problem is the need to keep track of recent decisions, so that on revisiting a Node via Parent one can turn right when left has been processed.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!
Herb

Comment: Have you had a look at Morris Inorder Traversal? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Morris_in-order_traversal_using_threading

Comment: Thank you, @msandiford. A threaded binary tree ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree)) would be wonderful to work with when accessing the tree in-order. Unfortunately, changing the tree layout is out of question. Since the tree is a prefix tree (aka Patricia trie), the most sensible way of accessing it is pre-order. Out of mere curiosity (since I can't change the tree layout anyway): there is no threaded binary tree for pre-order traversals, or is there?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a lot of constraints on this kind of exercises that I may be missing. I hope this is at least a bit usefull.

I am assuming that it is acceptable that the FSM is 'standing' at any given time on a 'current node' and therefore it has available inputs returning correct 0/1 values with info about this current node.

Inputs:

- AmIALeftChild  (equals 1 if the current node is hanging left of their parent node, otherwise 0)
- AmIARightChild (1 if I am hanging left of my parent node, otherwise 0)
- HaveLeftChild? (1 if I have a left child, otherwise 0 )
- HaveRightChild? (1 if I have a right child, otherwise 0 )

And is it ok to 'traverse it' by following the instructions in these 3 outputs?

Outputs:

- GoToLeftChild
- GoToRightChild
- GoUp

(only 1 of the 3 outputs can be true at any given time)

If both constraints are allowed, then you could build a FSM like this one:

States

- Startup
- NormalTraverse
- GoBackFromLeft
- GoBackFromRight
- Finished

This is the State machine:

```
Start -> just go to NormalTraverse state (assuming we are on the root, right)

NormalTraverse -> 
    If HaveLeftChild=1 Then
        Set GoToLeftChild=1  (and others outputs to 0)
        Go to NormalTraverse
    ElseIf HaveRightChild Then
        Set GoToRightChild=1 
        Go to NormalTraverse
    ElseIf AmIALeftChild Then
        Set GoUp=1
        Go to GoBackFromLeft
    ElseIf AmIARightChild Then
        Set GoUp=1
        Go to GoBackFromRight
    Else 
        Go to Finished.

GoBackFromLeft ->
    If HaveRightChild Then
        Set GoToRightChild=1 
        Go to NormalTraverse.   
    ElseIf AmIALeftChild Then
        Set GoUp=1
        Go to GoBackFromLeft
    ElseIf AmIARightChild Then
        Set GoUp=1
        Go to GoBackFromRight
    Else 
        Go to Finished.

GoBackFromRight
    If AmIALeftChild Then
        Set GoUp=1
        Go to GoBackFromLeft
    ElseIf AmIARightChild Then
        Set GoUp=1
        Go to GoBackFromRight
    Else 
        Go to Finished.
```

Excuse my english now and please note that the code is not procedural, and the "IF's" should be mutually exclusive after correctly 'expanding' them 'bit-wisely'. but I am writing it these way to save a little of time. If you don't understand what I mean, please ask.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. In fact, as was working at a similar solution concurrently and came back to post it, when I saw your work. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with, after many sheets of paper worth half a tree, mainly to draw many binary trees (especially degenerated ones) to verify that the FSM works correctly.

[image: A finite-state machine traversing a binary tree pre-order]

The only variable required to be accessible all the time is the start node. This can be just any node in the tree: the FSM traverses just this subtree.

It is assumed, that the start node was already processed (or needs no processing). But it would be easy to integrate, if this is not the case for your application: Before the GO LEFT step, just add a test for the start node: I AM START. If TRUE, Report, otherwise continue as shown.

The individual actions mean:

- **GO LEFT** - Make the current node's left child the current node, if there is any. The answer is OK if successful, or No Left if there is no such node.
- **GO RIGHT** - Make the current node's right child the current node, if there is any. The answer is OK if successful, or No Right if there is no such node.
- **GO UP** - Make the current node's parent the current node. There is just one resulting state. For the root, the parent does not exist, but the FSM will never attempt to access the root's parent.
- **I AM LEFT** - Test if the current node is its parent left child. The answer is True or False.
- **I AM RIGHT** - Test if the current node is its parent right child. The answer is True or False.
- **I AM START** - Test if the current node is the start node. The answer is True or False.

Comment: Your diagram uses same notation for inputs/condition-evaluation and states. which makes it a little confusing, if you change that it looks like my answer... It looks like it works ok

Comment: so which are the states of the state machine? Go Left/Right/Up are the outputs. I am Left/Right/Start are the inputs. Which ones are the states? even with the explanation you are still drawing a flow chart, not a state machine.

Comment: Sorry to be pushy. If this were homework, that is what a teacher would ask.

Comment: No problems, Gerardo, appreciated, in fact. The states are the two framed boxes: 

Report (as in: the actual node is the node currently visited, it is ready to be consumed in whatever way); and 

EndOfTree (as in: all nodes of the subtree specified by the start node were traversed).

Comment: Oh, I just realized about the framed boxes. But still It does not look 100% ok. Given that a FSM is not procedural, and given a state you can read your inputs, set your outputs and move to other state: you are not satisfying that rule, because on some cases you are making two chained decitions, as in "two different *sequential* outputs", between the start state and the next. That should not be allowed. (You are missing an intermediate state).
e.g: If I am low on the tree: Report->Cant go left, can't go right, So, I move up, as now I am not the root, I go right...: two moves wo/state change :(

Comment: You are right, Gerardo, my chart should not be called a FSM.